# Problem with IEEE References which has multiple papers of the same Authors

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am citing 3 different papers of the same author name for my conference paper.But the IEEE conference format does not shows the name of the 3rd author.

P.S. If I change the author name of the third reference, then it comes properly. Is it some problem with the IEEE conference template or some bug in overleaf?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\renewcommand{\citepunct}{,\penalty\citepunctpenalty\,}
\renewcommand{\citedash}{--} 


\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}

\begin{document}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology,
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\ Email: see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
ABC.
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\section{Introduction}


The introduction goes here \cite{Toliyat1,Toliyat2,Toliyat3}. 

\section{Section A}
First section


\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.

\section*{Acknowledgment}

The authors would like to thank...

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

The following lines are for bibliiography having filename as "references.bib".

```
@ARTICLE{Toliyat1,  author={H. A. {Toliyat} and T. A. {Lipo} and J. C. {White}},  journal={IEEE Transactions on Energy Conversion},   title={Analysis of a concentrated winding induction machine for adjustable speed drive applications. I. Motor analysis},   year={1991},  volume={6},  number={4},  pages={679-683},  doi={10.1109/60.103641}}

@ARTICLE{Toliyat2,  author={H. A. {Toliyat} and T. A. {Lipo} and J. C. {White}},  journal={IEEE Transactions on Energy Conversion},   title={Analysis of a concentrated winding induction machine for adjustable speed drive applications. II. Motor design and performance},   year={1991},  volume={6},  number={4},  pages={684-692},  doi={10.1109/60.103642}}

@ARTICLE{Toliyat3,  author={H. A. {Toliyat} and T. A. {Lipo}},  journal={IEEE Transactions on Energy Conversion},   title={Analysis of concentrated winding induction machines for adjustable speed drive applications-experimental results},   year={1994},  volume={9},  number={4},  pages={695-700},  doi={10.1109/60.368339}}
```

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you encase the authors' surnames in curly braces?

Comment: It seems to me like you're claiming that the bib entry for the 1994 publication should show three authors. Is this impression correct? Please advise.

Comment: I get `! File ended while scanning use of \author.` if I try to use your example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I ignore the errors generated by the ill-formed author markup I get a bibliography of

[image]

I would guess you are asking about the dash this is a an intentional style feature of the IEEE publications it's read as "ditto" or repeated author. Don't change this if submitting to the IEEE journal.

Comment: Sorry for the error generated by that author markup. Yes, you are correct this dash gets generated in the pdf. Is this a commonly acceptable format as I am submitting it at the conference?

Comment: @ShivamChakraborty if the conference organisers asked you to use this bibtex style they are asking for that style, it is not uncommon